# How to automatically supply username and password for proxy authentication?

Tags: windows-7, proxy, authentication

Some applications don't provide interface to enter username and password for the proxy, hence, can't connect to the network/internet.

- Is there a way to save the unsername and password somwhere so that it's provided automatically when connecting through the proxy?
- If not, is there a simple and clean work around? i.e. doesn't require installing few applications here and there and/or hacking the registry or system files ... etc.

I'm on Windows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the code works.  Sometimes you can simply add username:password@proxyaddress
like this:

bob:obo@google.com

but it is entirely dependent on if the code will handle it correctly.

Also, adding proxy information in internet settings (in control panel or ie) will force those proxy settings to work on most apps but not all.  Some programs have their own settings that are enforced instead of pulling from windows.  In those cases, there may be certain config files you could pass along the proxy info in when it's installed or update through a network update or something like that.  Is this just generally for random apps you run into this problem with, or a certain app?

Comment: I don't have the code of the applications in question so I don't know how they were written. You can think of may applications like that; as simple as `ping` or a bit more complex like `SkyDrive`. The `username:password@proxyaddress` works if the application gives you the option to specify that; what I'm looking for is specifying it somewhere globally. In internet settings you can only specify the proxy not the authentication information.

Comment: that didn't work